# How many distinct functions can be defined from set A to B?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In my discrete mathematics class our notes say that between set $A$ (having $6$ elements) and set $B$ (having $8$ elements), there are $8^6$ distinct functions that can be formed, in other words: $|B|^{|A|}$ distinct functions. But no explanation is offered and I can't seem to figure out why this is true. Can anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Let set $A$ have $a$ elements and set $B$ have $b$ elements. Each element in $A$ has $b$ choices to be mapped to. Each such choice gives you a unique function. Since each element has $b$ choices, the total number of functions from $A$ to $B$ is
$$\underbrace{b \times b \times b \times \cdots b}_{a \text{ times}} = b^a$$

Answer (score 76):

A function on a set involves running the function on *every element* of the set A, each one producing some result in the set B.  So, for the first run, every element of A gets mapped to an element in B.  The question becomes, how many different mappings, all using *every element* of the set A, can we come up with?  Take this example, mapping a 2 element set A, to a 3 element set B.  There are 9 different ways, all beginning with both 1 *and* 2, that result in some different combination of mappings over to B.

[image]

The number of functions from A to B is |B|^|A|, or $3^2$ = 9.

Comment: Very thorough. Sadly I doubt the original poster will see it though.

Comment: Very good graphical approach. Helped me understand that the number of functions from set A is the number of functions counted silmutanuously

Comment: Congrats for your fifth badge !

Comment: So if the output for 1 remains the same but the output of 2 changes then is it considered as a new function? So is this the reason why we are multiplying instead of adding?

Answer (score 10):

Let's say for concreteness that $A$ is the set $\{p,q,r,s,t,u\}$, and $B$ is a set with $8$ elements distinct from those of $A$. Let's try to define a function $f:A\to B$.

What is $f(p)$?  It could be any element of $B$, so we have 8 choices.

What is $f(q)$?  It could be any element of $B$, so we have 8 choices.

...

What is $f(u)$?  It could be any element of $B$, so we have 8 choices.

So there are $8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8\cdot8 = 8^6$ ways to choose values for $f$, and each possible set of choices defines a different function $f$.  So that's how many functions there are.

Comment: Is the set of all such functions denoted by $B^A$?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You know that a function gives a unique value for each entry, if the function $f\colon A\to B$ where $|A|=n, ~|B|=m$, then for $a\in A$, you have $m$ values to assign. then for every $a\in A$, you can take |B| values, since $|A|$ have $n$ elements, then you have $|B|^{|A|}$ choices.

Answer (score 1):

The cardinality of $B^A$ is the same if $A$ (resp. $B$) is replaced with a set containing the same number of elements as  $A$ (resp. $B$).

Set $b = |B$|. When $b \lt 2$ there is little that needs to be addressed, so we assume $b \ge 2$. Assume $|A| = n$.

A well known result of elementary number theory states that if $a$ is a natural number and $0 \le a \lt b^n$ then it has one and only one base-$\text{b}$ representation,

$$\tag 1  a = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_k\, b^k \text{ with } 0 \le x_k \lt b$$

Associate to every $a$ in the initial integer interval $[0, b^n)$ the set of ordered pairs

$$\tag 2  \{(k,x_k) \, | \, 0 \le k \lt n \text{ and the base-}b \text{ representation of } a \text{ is given by (1)}\}$$

This association is a bijective enumeration of $[0, b^n)$ onto the set of all functions 
mapping $[0,n-1]$ to $[0,b-1]$.

Since $[0, b^n)$ has $b^n$ elements, we know how to count all the functions from one finite set into another.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the definition that there is a bijection from $\mathrm{Func}(A,B)$ to $\prod_{i \in A}B_i$ where each $B_i$ is a copy of $B$. Thus the cardinal of $\mathrm{Func}(A,B)$ is equal to the cardinal of $\prod_{i \in A}B_i$. In particular, when $A,B$ are finite sets, we have $$ \# \ \mathrm{Func}(A,B) = \# B^{\# A}. $$