# Why does $B^A$, not $B\cdot A$, define set of all functions from set $A$ to set $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Define $A = \{a, b\}$ and $B = \{x, y, z\}$.

According to my readings, the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$ can be defined by $|B|^{|A|}$. This would dictate that there are $3^2$ possible functions, or $9$ functions, from my example.

I do not understand why it would not instead be $|B| \cdot |A|$, or 6 functions. I do recognize that for a set $A$ of $n$ elements and a set $B$ of $m$ elements, each element from $A$ can be linked to $m$ elements from $B$.

For my above example, I am thinking the resultant functions would be defined by the following sequences:

$(a, x), (a, y), (a, z), (b, x), (b, y), (b, z)$

As I see it, there are $6$ possible sequences. Can someone explain to me what I am misunderstanding?

EDIT: beautiful, makes much more sense now. Thank you all.

Comment: See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223240/how-many-distinct-functions-can-be-defined-from-set-a-to-b)

Comment: Please try to recall the definition of a function.

Comment: An element of $B \cdot A$ involves choosing an element of $B$ and choosing an element of $A$. On the other hand, an element of $B^A$ involves choosing an element of $B$ *for each* element of $A$.

Comment: Your error is that a function is not one of the six couples, but a pair of couples (one for $a$ and one for $b$); thus you have nine combinations of pair of couples ....

Answer (score 5):

A function is a mapping from each of the domain set to a range set.
Therefore a function can be defined as a set of pairs which matches each domain element to a range element (i.e a single pair is not a function).
For each element in the domain (n elements) you are free to choose one of the elements in the range (m elements) and therefore there are that much functions:
$n*n*...*n = n^m$

In your example the different functions would be:
$\{(a,x),(b,x)\}$,
$\{(a,x),(b,y)\}$,
$\{(a,x),(b,z)\}$,
$\{(a,y),(b,x)\}$,
$\{(a,y),(b,y)\}$,
$\{(a,y),(b,z)\}$,
$\{(a,z),(b,x)\}$,
$\{(a,z),(b,y)\}$,
$\{(a,z),(b,z)\}$.

Answer (score 4):

A function will tell you  which value of $B$ the function gives for each element of $A$. Nine examples of functions:

$$f_1(a)=x, \; f_1(b)=x$$
$$f_2(a)=x, \; f_2(b)=y$$
$$f_3(a)=x, \; f_3(b)=z$$
$$f_4(a)=y, \; f_4(b)=x$$
$$f_5(a)=y, \; f_5(b)=y$$
$$f_6(a)=y, \; f_6(b)=z$$
$$f_7(a)=z, \; f_7(b)=x$$
$$f_8(a)=z, \; f_8(b)=y$$
$$f_9(a)=z, \; f_9(b)=z$$

Comment: Wow, your answer was simultanious to mine, and we even ordered the functions in the same order!

Answer (score 3):

There are $9$ functions from $A$ to $B$ as that is the number $|B|^{|A|}$. Here they are:

- $a\mapsto x$, $b\mapsto x$
- $a\mapsto x$, $b\mapsto y$
- $a\mapsto x$, $b\mapsto z$
- $a\mapsto y$, $b\mapsto x$
- $a\mapsto y$, $b\mapsto y$
- $a\mapsto y$, $b\mapsto z$
- $a\mapsto z$, $b\mapsto x$
- $a\mapsto z$, $b\mapsto y$
- $a\mapsto z$, $b\mapsto z$

Answer (score 0):

In your example, for each element in $A$ there are three choices for it's image under the function. There are two elements in $A$. So the total number of choices is $3 \cdot 3 = 3^2$. Maybe you are assuming the functions are injective, which need not be the case.