# Number of functions from domain to codomain

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let A and B be finite sets. Let a be the size of A. Let b be the size of B. Assume
0 < a < b.

(a) How many functions are there with domain A and co-domain B?
(b) How many one-to-one functions are there with domain A and co-domain B?
(c) How many one-to-one functions are there with domain B and co-domain A?
(NOTE- domain is B, co-domain is A.)
(d) How many onto functions are there with domain A and co-domain B?

How are we supposed to figure out how many functions there are? Couldn't it be pretty much infinite since each function can do things differently and still get the same value?

How would we solve a)?

Would both b) be a or !b/!a? and would c) be 0?

I understand that d) should be 0, but what if the domain was B and co-domain A? how would we solve that then?

-thanks and any explanation would be appreciated

Comment: Functions are uniquely determined by their values, so if functions have the same values on all elements of the domain, they cannot "do things differently".

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah okay I didn't know thats how they were defined. so would a) be B?

Comment: @Mark There are $b^a$ number of functions.

Comment: or would it be more complicated than that. Like B^B

Comment: @Rustyn oh okay. I understand that now. B different mappings for each element of A. so b * b * b.  thanks

Comment: @Mark sure no problem.

Comment: @Rustyn could you double check me on b) and c) and possibly elaborate on how we would solve d) if the codomains and domains were switched? Sorry if that's asking for a lot. I'm trying to get a good grasp on these concepts

Comment: @Mark, You may find the following and the link therein helpful. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334420/number-of-onto-functions

Comment: This may also be helpful. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223240/how-many-distinct-functions-can-be-defined-from-set-a-to-b