# How many function from $\{0,1\}^{n}$ to $\{0,1\}^{m}$ there is

Tags: combinatorics, functions, logic

I am new to combinatorics and struggling with the following quastion:

> How many different functions $$f:\left\{0,1\right\}^{n}\rightarrow \left\{0,1\right\}^{m}$$ can be found? if: $$m \geq n$$

How I imagine it:

every $\left\{0,1\right\}^{n}$
is a series of $1$-th and $0$-th in the length of $n$,
so for every element we can choose to change it to ($0$ or $1$) or to leave it without changing it.

So for every element we got $2$ options and we got $n$ elements so we got $2^{n}$ options **correct**?

Now, the moment we finish all the elements ($n$) for every **new** place we got $2$ options - $0$ or $1$ and we are left with $m-n$ places to fill so we got $2^{m-n}$ options, **correct**?

The final answer is : $$2^{m}\cdot2^{m-n}=2^{m}$$

Is this correct or I completely misunderstood some-thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A,B$ finite sets, the number of function $f:A \rightarrow B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$ ([why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223240/how-many-distinct-functions-can-be-defined-from-set-a-to-b)).

In this case the number of considered function is $(2^m)^{2^n}$

---

Comment: Thats great Thank you!